# is it possible to use getRowsData without a range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google app scrips and I want to iterate through a spreadsheet that will be updated weekly. (this is why i dont want to set a range i want to be able to iterate through the entire sheet.)

Is this possible? If yes can you give an example of how this would be done?

and if this isn't a good idea, why not?

Thank you!

**Example code**

```
function doGet(e){   


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('key in here');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1);
var dataRange =  range.getValue().toString();

 app.add(app.createHTML("There are " + dataRange + " posts today"))
 return app;
```

Something like this, but I want to be able to see the whole sheet not just the range

Comment: Can you post some code of your attempt.Code speaks louder than words

Comment: He's probably looking for the [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) function

Comment: @Srik Hey, i added an example Instead of just the range i'd like to see the whole sheet.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu doesnt the getDataRange also require a range within the spreadsheet?

Comment: getDataRange returns the full range within a sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Henrique Abreu and Srik provided you with correct answer - getDataRange on sheet should serve your purpose.

```
function doGet(e){   
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetId').getSheetByName('sheetName');
 var data =  sheet.getDataRange().getValues();;
 ...
}
```

data is now 2-dimensional array, you can iterate through it, get last column/row containing content etc. Please read through class reference here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate over the sheet by itself, but always iterate over the vales of range.

However you don't have to use a fixed range but can compute the range at every script execution.

To do this you could use getlastcolumn() and getLastRow().
This two methods return the last column or row with content in it.

A commodity method is getDataRange() which directly gives you the range with data in it.

Every script execution this range will extend over all your cells and columns with content.

Look at the example from [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// This represents ALL the data
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();

// This logs the spreadsheet in CSV format with a trailing comma
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   var row = "";
   for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
     if (values[i][j]) {
       row = row + values[i][j];
     }
     row = row + ",";
   }
   Logger.log(row);
}
```

Hope that helps.